# How do i set up termios parameters in C++ for a Raspberry PI USB UART connection?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, usb, uart, lora

I have a RPI 3 and a LoRa USB module and I'm writing some code in C++ for the port connection to the device.  I am able to connect to the port (which is assigned as ttyUSBPort1 in a udev rule).  However when I am sending data to the port, I'm getting an error.  I just don't know enough about termios and port communications to determine if that's the problem (yes, I've read the manpage).

The LoRa module is a RN2903 device and the following is the UART Interface instructions on the reference sheet:

> All of the RN2903 module’s settings and commands are transmitted over UART using
>   the ASCII interface.
>   All commands need to be terminated with < CR >< LF > *(spaces added for formatting)* and any replies they generate will
>   also be terminated by the same sequence.
>   The default settings for the UART interface are 57600 bps, 8 bits, no parity, 1 Stop bit,
>   no flow control.

When sending commands, I can see that the device is responding with "invalid_parameter" by monitoring the port with

`sudo cat /dev/ttyUSBPort1`

I am assuming either I have some of the termios flags set incorrectly, or the write command set up incorrectly.  Here's the code I have that sets up the port:

```
int openPort(void) {
struct termios tty;
memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
if ((usb_port = open(device, O_RDWR))>=0) {// | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC
    std::cout << "DEVICE OPENED: " << device << " handle number: " << usb_port << std::endl;
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open serial device");
    return -1;
}
if(tcgetattr(usb_port, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %i \n", errno);
}
cfsetispeed(&tty, B57600);
cfsetospeed(&tty, B57600);

tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout

tcflush( usb_port, TCIFLUSH );
if (tcsetattr(usb_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %i\n", errno);
}
return usb_port;
}
```

And here's the call command to get the version information from the device:

```
void radioCMD(string tmp) {
string tmp2 = tmp + "\r\n";
int n = tmp2.length();
char cmd[n];
strcpy(cmd, tmp2.c_str());
std::cout << write(usb_port, cmd, sizeof(cmd)) << " " << cmd << "Writing to " << usb_port << " Delay: " << delay << " Command Size: " << sizeof(cmd) << std::endl;
}
void setupRadio() {
radioCMD("sys get ver");
usleep(delay);
}
```

When writing to the console std::cout, I am seeing this:

```
13 sys get ver
Writing to 3 Delay: 200000 Command Size: 13
```

showing that the message is indeed being correctly written.

The cat output from the device should respond with something like this (from the datasheet):

> 2.3.6.1
>   sys get ver
>   Response: RN2903 X.Y.Z MMM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS, where X.Y.Z is the firmware
>   version, MMM is month, DD is day, HH:MM:SS is hour, minutes, seconds (format: [HW]
>   [FW] [Date] [Time]). [Date] and [Time] refer to the release of the firmware.
>   This command returns the information related to the hardware platform, firmware
>   version, release date and time-stamp on firmware creation.
>   Example: sys get ver

What I actually get is "invalid_param\r\n", which is the appropriate response from the device if something in the call is not correct.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong here?

**EDIT**

thanks to Ted for pointing me in the right direction and simplifying my code.  There were two missing termios flags.  Once I set these (last two), it works fine.

```
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
        ***ADDITIONAL TWO FLAGS THAT FIXED IT****
tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR; // Prevent conversion of newline to carriage return/line feed
tty.c_oflag &= ~OCRNL; // Prevent conversion of newline to carriage return/line feed
```

New Write Call Function:

```
void radioCMD(string cmd) {
    cmd += "\r\n";
    write(usb_port, cmd.c_str(), cmd.size());
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the mode you get by default when opening the device isn't working before you started setting it?

Suggestion: Remove this part when sending: `string tmp2 = tmp + "\r\n";
int n = tmp2.length();
char cmd[n];
strcpy(cmd, tmp2.c_str());`. Instead do `tmp += "\r\n";` and then use `tmp.c_str()` and `tmp.size()` directly in the `write` call.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  The change you recommended is what works, in conjunction with a few different termios flags.

Comment: *"Once I set these (last two), it works fine"* -- Your program is unreliable because it depends on additional termios attributes to be set, namely ICANON and OPOST.  For reliable operation, your program should configure all relevant termios attributes that it requires.  Do a simple test: issue the command `stty raw -F /dev/ttyUSBPort1` before you run your program.  BTW using `sudo` to access a terminal device is unwise and should be unnecessary.  VMIN and VTIME are not used in canonical mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) that is one `char` too short to fit the null terminator of the C string:

```
void radioCMD(string tmp) {
    string tmp2 = tmp + "\r\n";
    int n = tmp2.length();
    char cmd[n];                       // should be n+1 for strcpy to work
    strcpy(cmd, tmp2.c_str());         // undefined behavior \0 is written out of bounds
    write(usb_port, cmd, sizeof(cmd)); // sizeof(cmd) should be replaced by n
}
```

A better alternative would be to use `std::memcpy` instead of `std::strcpy` to copy the C string *without* the null terminator - and to avoid `VLA`:s.

An even better alternative would be to use the `std::string` you get as a parameter directly:

```
void radioCMD(string cmd) {
    cmd += "\r\n";
    write(usb_port, cmd.c_str(), cmd.size());
}
```

It may not be the only problem, but as the `std::strcpy` currently makes your program have undefined behavior, it's a good place to start.

Comment: Ted, your void radioCMD function works, but just as an fyi in case anyone else runs into this problem, I had to add two more tty termios flags (but you put me on the right track thinking about the CRLF.  I'll edit original post to add the termios flags.

Comment: @Max Great! Perhaps it'd even be better to `|` all the I/O and control flags together from `0` instead. :-)